# Processing Symfony Form in Embedded Controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I am trying to embed a controller in a Twig template like this:

```
{{ render(controller('IRCGlobalBundle:MailingList:join')) }}
```

This controller renders a basic form to join a mailing list:

```
namespace IRC\GlobalBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use IRC\GlobalBundle\Entity\MailingList;
use IRC\GlobalBundle\Form\Type\MailingListType;

class MailingListController extends BaseController
{
    public function joinAction(Request $request) {
        $this->getSiteFromRequest($request);
        $mailingList = new MailingList;
        $mailingList->setSite($this->site);
        $form = $this->createForm(new MailingListType(), $mailingList);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            echo "submitted form";
        } else {
            echo "unsubmitted form";
        }

        return $this->render('IRCGlobalBundle:Forms:join_mailing_list.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the $form->isSubmitted() method never returns true so the form submission cannot be validated/handled.  What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change the target of the form to point to my embedded controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because the form will be rendered like this `<form action="">` so it will post the information to the same page but since you are rendering the form using a sub-request the new sub-request will not carry any form data.

The easiest way to solve this issue is by hacking the form action attribute and make it send the request to `joinAction` and you can `redirect` or `forward` the request after handling the form to the page where the user came from.

something like this should work:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MailingListType(), $mailingList, array(
     'action'   => //generate a url to joinAction
));
```

Comment: How to generate the url since the joinAction does not have Routing ?